# Mysql Natural sorting in varchar field

Tags: mysqli, natural-sort

Is there anyway to sort the string with number field by its number only
I have a value like this

```
subject_code    
DE 312  
DE 313  
DE 315  
Eng 311   
COMP 314
```

can it be sort like this

```
subject_code 
Eng 311   
DE 312  
DE 313   
COMP 314    
DE 315
```

I tried

```
order by SOUNDEX(subject_code),LENGTH(subject_code),subject_code
```

but it does not work as expected.

Thank you for your any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround to your situation uses string operations to obtain the numerical subject code and use it for sorting.

```
SELECT
    subject_code
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CAST(SUBSTR(subject_code,
                INSTR(subject_code, ' ') + 1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

However, you should really be storing the text and numerical code in separate columns.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks I should have separated col with int and string